# How to add extra spaces / lines in XMLWriter php document

Tags: php, xmlwriter

I am using XMLWriter in php to create a document , but I need to format it by adding some more lines and spaces between elements and components. How can I do it. Please have a look of following example

PHP code :

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP XMLWriter - How to create a simple xml
 */

//create a new xmlwriter object
$xml = new XMLWriter(); 
//using memory for string output
$xml->openMemory(); 
//set the indentation to true (if false all the xml will be written on one line)
$xml->setIndent(true);
//create the document tag, you can specify the version and encoding here
$xml->startDocument(); 
//Create an element
$xml->startElement("Customer"); 
//Write to the element
$xml->writeElement("id", "1");
$xml->writeElement("name", "Oluwafemi"); 
$xml->writeElement("address", "Cresent Drive, TX");
$xml->endElement(); //End the element
//output the xml (obviosly this output could be written to a file)
echo htmlentities($xml->outputMemory()); 
?>
```

Output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customer>
 <id>1</id>
 <name>Oluwafemi</name>
 <address>Cresent Drive, TX</address>
</Customer>
```

But I need to generate output like as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Customer>

     <id>1</id>
     <name>Oluwafemi</name>
     <address>Cresent Drive, TX</address>

</Customer>
```

Comment: This is not supported by xmlwriter.

Comment: @u_mulder is there any alternative ways

Comment: You can generate you xml manually, something like `$s = "<Customer>\n\n    <id>" . $id . "</id>"`, etc

Comment: @u_mulder Ya that was the last way i preferred . Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike what the comments say, it *IS* very much supported, for your specific case just use:

```
$xml->setIndentString("     ");
```